# Access 365 Split Form - Datasheet moves when I click in it

Tags: ms-access

When I click in the datasheet of my split form, the datasheet shifts up and to the left. I've attached a picture.  I'm hoping that someone can help me because this is SUPER frustrating.  Thank you in advance!  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nly.png

Comment: This appears to be a design not coding issue and therefore question not appropriate for SO. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate the problem.  More information was needed